# jQuery scrolling animation on scroll becomes recursive

Tags: jquery, animation, recursion, scroll

I am trying to write some code for full page scroll, but I get stuck in a sort of recursive function. I want to scroll up or down the full page, depending on the direction of the scroll. I use scroll animation for it. The problem is, while the animation is in action, the scroll event gets called, and it's like an infinite loop of some sort. Ca I stop the scroll event until the end of animation?

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
    var scroll = "#section2";
    current_scroll = "#section2";
    alert(current_scroll);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scroll).offset().top
    }, 2000);

   } else {
    var scroll = "#section1";
    current_scroll = "#section1";
        alert(current_scroll);
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scroll).offset().top
    }, 2000);

   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Can you also add the html? And what would be really nice would be if you could include a JSFiddle with your problem.

Comment: You might want to reconsider this method. Locking in a user to watch your animation for 2 seconds may make them decide to visit a different site.

Comment: @KristianBarrett, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/z89ge8gq/

Comment: @Mottie, it can be less time, that is not the issue in question here.

Comment: Well then check out [this plugin](http://mottie.github.io/visualNav/stepper.html) as it might do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Mottie, thanks! I ended up using this http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home until I figure out how to write my own :)